# Are JSP pages compatible with HTML5 syntax?

Tags: html, jsp

I'm working with Tomcat 9 and use a site, with a few JSP pages. I have Sheet.jsp, a self-posting page: it has a form, say F, containing two fields, A and B; there's also a submit button, S. A is an input field, B is readonly and shows the result.
I want to use HTML5, so I put at the beginning of Sheet.jsp.
So I wrote:

```
<form id=F action=POST>
    <input type=Text id=A>
    <input type=Text id=B readonly>
    <input type=submit id=S>
</form>
```

I used "id" attribute, not "name" attribute, according to HTML5.
So doing, the page doesn't work.
If I write:

```
<form name=F action=POST>
    <input type=Text name=A>
    <input type=Text name=B readonly>
    <input type=submit name=S>
</form>
```

the page works fine.

So, my question is: is there any compatibility issue between JSP pages and HTML5 ?

Perhaps JSP generates HTML4 text only ?

Thanks in advance. PS: I apologize if it's a known and already answered question, but I tried and wasn't able to find it.

Comment: JSPs just produce HTML - they are perfectly compatible with HTML5.

Comment: I think so too, but I can't explain the problem I exposed

Comment: Names and IDs are used for different purposes - since you didn't actually show us how you are using those attributes we can't know what is wrong. Also, names and IDs are both fine for HTML5, not sure why you think names are not allowed. You also need quotes around attribute values.

Comment: Okay, as soon as possible I write down my page into my question, perhaps it would become clearer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've solved the problem.
The name attribute is necessary when the form is submitted, and only input tags with the attribute name are submitted. Without the name attribute defined, nothing is submitted.

The id attribute can be used on the client side (e.g. into Javascript code), but not for submission.